# Why does multicast sockets work as intended on system with two network interfaces?

Tags: windows, sockets, networking

I am working on the SW of a test equipment. This system includes a PC (running Windows 10) and multiple Raspberry Pi units (and a bunch of equipment not relevant for this question). The PC has two physical network adapters:

- NIC1 (identified by 192.168.0.122 in routing table below)
- NIC2 (identified by 192.168.130.25 in routing table below)

NIC1 is connected to a switch connecting all network nodes inside the rack containing the test equipment. Thus, it is an internal network not connected to the outside world. There is a multicast based protocol in use to communicate between the PC and the various Raspberry Pi units.

NIC2 is the public interface to the test equipment. Its purpose is to enable automation of the test equipment. There is a TCP server running on the PC waiting for connections on NIC2 using a domain specific protocol. NIC2 is connected to a laboratory subnet, physically separated from the internal network on NIC1.

The test equipment works fine. But recently I realized I had forgotten to bind the sockets for the multicast based protocol to NIC1 on the PC. For some reason the system have worked fine anyway - even though I have shut it down and restarted it many, many times. It is not a coincidence, it is definitely a deterministic behaviour.

This is how the routing table looks like on the PC:

```
===========================================================================
Active Routes:
Network Destination        Netmask          Gateway       Interface  Metric
          0.0.0.0          0.0.0.0      192.168.0.1    192.168.0.122     25
          0.0.0.0          0.0.0.0  192.168.130.254   192.168.130.25     25
        127.0.0.0        255.0.0.0         On-link         127.0.0.1    331
        127.0.0.1  255.255.255.255         On-link         127.0.0.1    331
  127.255.255.255  255.255.255.255         On-link         127.0.0.1    331
      192.168.0.0    255.255.255.0         On-link     192.168.0.122    281
    192.168.0.122  255.255.255.255         On-link     192.168.0.122    281
    192.168.0.255  255.255.255.255         On-link     192.168.0.122    281
    192.168.130.0    255.255.255.0         On-link    192.168.130.25    281
   192.168.130.25  255.255.255.255         On-link    192.168.130.25    281
  192.168.130.255  255.255.255.255         On-link    192.168.130.25    281
        224.0.0.0        240.0.0.0         On-link         127.0.0.1    331
        224.0.0.0        240.0.0.0         On-link     192.168.0.122    281
        224.0.0.0        240.0.0.0         On-link    192.168.130.25    281
  255.255.255.255  255.255.255.255         On-link         127.0.0.1    331
  255.255.255.255  255.255.255.255         On-link     192.168.0.122    281
  255.255.255.255  255.255.255.255         On-link    192.168.130.25    281
===========================================================================
```

For example: there is one socket on the PC joining the multicast group 239.255.4.0:90. According to the routing table both NICs have the same network destinations and netmasks for multicast routes (as expected), but also the same metric. A lower metric value for NIC1 would have explained the behaviour. With equal metrics I would have expected a more random behaviour.

My main question is: **How come the multicast sockets always select the NIC1 adapter on the PC?**

*(Just for the protocol: I have now bound the multicast sockets on the PC to NIC1. There is no difference, the system still works fine. I feel a bit more confident, though. But since this is the first time I am working with multiple network adapters I am still a bit worried that I have misunderstood something.)*

Comment: You're looking at the routing table metrics. Did you also check the interface metric? You can see it using Powershell's `Get-NetIPInterface`. Routing tables don't work for multicast anyway, so I'd expect the default network interface is going to be chosen if you don't specify the interface explicitly. It would be interesting if you could test whether multicast stops working after changing the default interface.

Comment: @Luaan Unfortunately I don't have access to the system right now. It is in another city... I didn't know the routing table doesn't work for multicast, but it kind of make sense. I tested Powershell's `Get-NetIPInterface` on my own computer and can see the interface metrics there. I guess on the test equipment it will show a lower interface metric for the NIC1. How do I change the default interface?

Comment: I think it should be in the network connections control panel -> alt -> advanced -> advanced settings -> provider order. Or you can force a different metric on the interface in adapter properties - no idea if the two are in any way related, but both might affect the default multicast interface.